# How do you infer types of props in the component of Vue 3?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

How to get the value of props in the component of vue3
For the following components, I want to infer the types of props and data through the generic parameter passing of `defineComponent`, but the value of props cannot be obtained by doing so. How can I modify it?

```
import { defineComponent , Prop, Ref, toRefs} from 'vue'

interface MProps {
    day:  number
}

interface MData {
    day: Ref<number>,
}

export default defineComponent<MProps, MData>({

    setup(props, content) {
        const { day } = toRefs(props)
        console.log('props.day', props.day)

        return  {
            day: day,
        }
    },

    render() {
        return <div>
            {this.day}
        </div>
    }
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using [the first signature](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/15baaf14f025f6b1d46174c9713a2ec517741d0d/packages/runtime-core/src/apiDefineComponent.ts#L83) of `defineComponent` which expects a direct `setup` function. But the problem is, it doesn't `extend` [`ComponentOptionsBase`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/15baaf14f025f6b1d46174c9713a2ec517741d0d/packages/runtime-core/src/componentOptions.ts#L81) for you to add a `render` function (such implementation is only available in the other overloads/signatures).

However, if you prefer, you could return a JSX element as a [`RenderFunction`](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/15baaf14f025f6b1d46174c9713a2ec517741d0d/packages/runtime-core/src/componentOptions.ts#L79) with the first signature; although sadly, as discussed on the comments down below—this is not working as expected (in that the props passed by the parent/consuming component actually get passed as DOM properties instead!). Hope we're not missing something very obvious here, like having to actually define the props somewhere?

```
export default defineComponent<MProps, MData>(function setup(props) {
  const { day } = toRefs(props);

  return () => (
    <div>{day}</div>
  );
})
```

If you are okay with using the second signature, however, the following approach (with [Props Annotation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/typescript-support.html#annotating-props)) will give you the same effect of type inference at the expense of your structured contracts (`interface`).

```
import { defineComponent, PropType, toRefs } from 'vue';

type MonthNames = 'January' | 'February' | 'March';

interface ITodo {
  done: boolean;
  notes: string;
  dateCreated: Date;
  dateModified: Date;
}

export default defineComponent({
  props: {
    // We won't have issue with primitive values as they can be automatically inferred
    day: Number,

    // Here's our challenge. And `PropType` to the rescue!
    monthNames: Array as PropType<MonthNames>,

    todo: Object as PropType<ITodo>,

    todoList: Array as PropType<ITodo[]>,

    // Another variation: With custom class 
    todoList2: class TodoList implements Array<ITodo> {

    }
  },

  setup(props) {
    const { day, monthNames, todo, todoList } = toRefs(props);

    // If you use VSCode, you should get intellisense with the list of month names 
    // as soon as you type an opening quote
    monthNames.value = 'January';

    todo.value.done = true;

    todoList.value.push({
      done: false
    });

    return {}
  }
});
```

Comment: Do note that you should not modify props directly, the above is just an example that shows how type inference would work with props annotation.

Comment: Hahaha I understand a little bit, the signatures in 4 correspond to different inputs. In fact, what I want is the fourth signature `ComponentOptionsWithObjectProps` .Generics give constraints on props, and the objects passed in to `defineComponent` functions also have props properties. How to use this correctly .

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure what you mean, can you elaborate? But yeah I think my example above actually uses the fourth signature.

Comment: Ah I think I got your point. So, I played around with the different overloads and ended up using the first one, which seems to be closer to your original attempt with the props constraints. All you'd need to do is to pass a `setup` function as the first argument of `defineComponent<MProps, MData>`. However, I ran into a problem where it's not binding any props on the component when assigned a value by the parent/consuming component. I wonder if that's a bug somehow.

Comment: @silk There has to be a way. I was looking into the fourth overload and found that there's this third constraint named `D` which *isn't* optional and not descriptive either. Not quite sure what that's meant to be.

Comment: awesome! It's what you understand. When I try to use` defineComponent<MProps, MData>`. This way to constrain the types of props,I should be able to include them in the function parameters. But if I don’t define it, when the parent component passes properties to it, it will be passed as a DOM property instead of a props property passed to the Com component instance.

Comment: Exactly, if you look into [the TS implementation](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/blob/15baaf14f025f6b1d46174c9713a2ec517741d0d/packages/runtime-core/src/apiDefineComponent.ts#L82) for that, it clearly says that it uses user-defined props `interface`, yet for some reason it doesn't work (and you're right, the props passed by the parent get passed as DOM properties instead).

Comment: D is the state object returned by the data function of the value object.
The difference between the third signature and the fourth is that the props properties passed are of different types. One is an array and the other is an object that satisfies the PropType type, so I guess that props cannot be restricted by passing parameters to the generic type. Props must be added to the function parameters. Attribute to constrain

Comment: That's it, i will use the method you proposed.

Comment: Hm, true and interesting. The fact that they decided to go with `D` is probably just as confusing as having [`createVNode` aliased as `h`](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/render-function.html#h-arguments). But we are used to it anyway, lol.